# Missing com.apple.xbs folder, how do I get it?

Tags: python, error-handling, pyqt, appkit

/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1504.81.100/AppKit.subproj/NSBitmapImageRep.m:1296

is causing an error in a simple PyQt5 Python 3 program on Mac OS. How can I download this file?

```
2017-03-23 22:50:20.703 Python[94924:2805073] *** Assertion failure in - [NSBitmapImageRep initWithCGImage:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1504.81.100/AppKit.subproj/NSBitmapImageRep.m:1296
2017-03-23 22:50:20.734 Python[94924:2805073] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid   parameter not satisfying: cgImage != NULL'
```

program code:
http://pastebin.com/2HNqwY2C

Comment: You already own that file, however it is failing on line 1296.

Comment: why cant i find it in my computer? ive even checked the hidden folders. I could not find it on other mac computers i checked either, nor does it seem to be anywhere on the internet. @SB87

Comment: The file you should be looking for isn't named `NSBitmapImageRep.m:1296` but `NSBitmapImageRep.m` and it should be inside this folder: `/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1504.81.100/AppKit.subproj/` Do you have that folder?

Comment: Ps: and beware `/Library/` is another folder on macOS then `/Users/your_user_name/Library` so double check you are in the correct one..

Comment: Ah, and given the fact that is in the `Caches` directory it might well be that the program you talk about is creating it on the fly, then it apparently causes an error so the program quits, thereby possibly removing the file.. so you whould monitor the directory while you execute the program..

Comment: I checked both Libraries. The folder is not in either. 
Per reddit user:
"Lol, I meant Apple developers as in "Apple employees", internal developers. The error is with the internal Apple libraries complaining that QT is not doing something they expect, something related to images.
I would suggest removing everything you can remove from initUI (i.e. everything except .show() ) then add them back slowly to see where it trips up. As I said though, you'd get better feedback on the PyQt mailing list." He seems to think it is a folder only Apple employees have access to. @SB87

Comment: @SB87 will update but I think it has to do with the menu bar and the way Windows vs Mac handle menu bars in applications.

**UPDATE- THIS IS IT:** 
`mainMenu = self.menuBar()`

How to handle this through PyQt in Mac bc I know it works in Tkinter?

Comment: Well, PyQt, Qt and macOS has been troublesome for some time now.. please see [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270302/in-sierra-how-to-get-qt-5-8-0-pyqt-5-7-1-sip-4-19-python3-5-to-install) I asked on Ask Different some time ago, also notice the accepted answer.. The problem you are facing might be a small issue (that we have not yet been able to pinpoint) but it might also be related to larger problems with PyQt/macOS, in which case only Riverbank (company developing PyQt) might be able to solve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are hitting a bug in QT: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58344

Based on the report it should be fixed in QT 5.8.1

---

To answer the literal question posed: NSBitmapImageRep is a class in the AppKit framework, which QT uses when an app runs on a Mac. As the referenced reddit user mentioned: There are no source files on your system, even temporarily. The line numbers included in those crash reports are intended for diagnosis of issues if you submit the reports to QT or Apple.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the info. The only odd thing is that I do actually have that latest version installed. Is there a different command I should be using other than `mainMenu = self.menuBar()` ?

Comment: The latest version of Qt is 5.8.0, which is affected by this. Unfortunately there [isn't going to be a 5.8.1](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2017-February/028757.html), so this will be fixed in 5.9.0 which is [planned](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.9_Release) for end of May.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, this path references an Objective-C source file (`.m`), presumably from Apple's proprietary AppKit source code, and likely originated from an Apple-internal build machine where it was baked into one of the system libraries shipped with macOS:

```
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1504.81.100/AppKit.subproj/NSBitmapImageRep.m
```

While there is not much public documentation, it is likely that `com.apple.xbs` is an Apple-internal build system, given that it frequently seems to appear in error paths pointing to source files of Apple frameworks. A blog post from 2006 seems to confirm this:

> Building the source was also very difficult as **the internal Apple build system, XBS**, is very large, very involved, and was not documented outside Apple.

[http://www.synack.net/~bbraun/writing/oshistory.html](http://www.synack.net/%7Ebbraun/writing/oshistory.html)

Another source, from the WebKit mailing list in 2011:

> I don't think driving the build via a Makefile is a desirable option. **XBS (what Maciej has been referring to as Apple's central build system)** knows how to override Xcode configuration settings for projects that build using Xcode.

https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2011-March/016080.html